# How can I set visible to hide the jDialog (inside if condition) that is set visible shown (outside if loop)?

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jdialog

Here I want to open a `DialogFrame` containing an error message when a `buttonGroup` is not active & the search button is clicked. So inside the ActionEvent I have made the `DialogFrame` to  `setVisible(true)`. But when the button group is active & I click the search button (inside the `if` condition), the `setVisible(false)` doesn't seem to work, in other word the `DialogFrame` still pop ups!

How can I turn the visibility off of the `DialogFrame` inside the `if` condition?

```
private void jButtonSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    SrchEMsg sem = new SrchEMsg(this);
    sem.setVisible(true);
    sem.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sem.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


    if (bgGroup.getSelection() != null) {
        sem.setVisible(false); //doesn't work.
        SrchResult sr = new SrchResult();
        sr.setVisible(true);
        sr.pack();
        sr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the JDialog modal? If so, then it will block code flow after it has been set visible.

Comment: And why are you default setting it visible? Why not `sem.setVisible(bgGroup.getSelection() == null);`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use relevant tags for questions. The `JDialog` tag is relevant, the tag for your IDE is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to manipulate the visibility but simply not to create `sem` at all *if* some condition is met:

```
if (bgGroup.getSelection() == null) {
    // only handle `sem`
    SrchEMsg sem = new SrchEMsg(this);
    sem.setVisible(true);
    sem.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sem.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
} else {
    // only handle `sr`
    SrchResult sr = new SrchResult();
    sr.setVisible(true);
    sr.pack();
    sr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Get rid of

```
sem.setVisible(true);
```

and instead simply do

```
sem.setVisible(bgGroup.getSelection() == null);
```

only set it visible if need be

If instead your wish to set the dialog invisible *when* the user makes a selection, then you can't do this in dialog creation code, but rather need to respond to the appropriate event, such as an ActionListener or ItemListener added to your JRadioButtons.